# node.js merging multiple control flows

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am slowly starting to use node.js more and more as I find more uses for it.  I have a decent grasp on it, using express for simple REST services.  I am trying to use it to write a small utility script.  Imagine this very very simple example that fetches mysql rows, goes through each row and updates them and then prints "done".  Please ignore the fact that you could obviously do this with one mysql query:

```
q=mysql_query("select id from table");
while($r=mysql_fetch_array($q)){
  mysql_query("update table set col1 = 'whatever' where id=".$r['id']);
}
print "done here!";
```

To do this in node.js is more cumbersome; I can make the query, run through all the rows and issue the update with something like this:

```
doQuery("select id from table",function(rows){
   for(var i=0;i<rows.length;i++){
      doQuery("update table set col1='whatever' where id="+rows[i]['id'],function(){
         //do I do something here? this will run as many times as rows were returned in the select
      })
   }
})

function doQuery(sql, callback){//utility function to help do the query
    var mysqlconnection = mysql.createConnection({
        host     : 'localhost',
        user     : 'user',
        password : '********',
        database:  'dbname'
    });
    mysqlconnection.connect(function(err1){
        mysqlconnection.query(sql, function(error, results) {
            if(callback)callback(results)
        })
    })
}
```

So for this example, I make the single `select` query, and then I split my control flow into many flows.  How do I get this back down to one control flow?  Or, in other words, how can I simply console.log "done" when all the `updates` have finished?

I've seen promises might be helpful, but all those basic examples show a static number of queries, my issue is dynamic, and based on results from mysql.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [async](https://github.com/caolan/async), a popular nodejs module to process async tasks.

```
var async = require("async");

function doQuery(sql, callback){
  var mysqlconnection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'user',
    password : '********',
    database:  'dbname'
  });
  mysqlconnection.connect(function(err1){
    mysqlconnection.query(sql, function(error, results) {
      if(callback) callback(results);
    });
  });
}

function doUpdateQueryForEachRow(row, callback) {
  doQuery("update table set col1='whatever' where id=" + row.id, function (result) {
    callback(null, result); // the first parameter should be an error object
  });
}

doQuery("select id from table", function (rows) {
  async.map(rows, doUpdateQueryForEachRow, function (error, results) {
    // do something..
  });
});
```

Comment: This is great, can you please elaborate more? make the code more verbose? comments? I don't see how it is iterating over rows, and I don't see the `update` sql query. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should substitute your "for" loop with an iteration function:

```
function iterate (rowId) {
   if (rowId == rows.length - 1){
      // ... all updates done ...
   }

   doQuery("...update...", function () {
      iterate(rowId + 1);});
}(0);
```